# Combobox in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, combobox

I want to put a combobox in my datagridview. I've tried differents ways (creating a var list<>, creating an arraylist, ect...) and none is working. The thing is my column already exist because of my select query that show my database in the datagridview. But the column is empty since in my database the column is fill with NULL value.

I have two choices : Creating a combobox and do an addcolumn, or if you know how to do it link my combobox to the already existing column. And obviously i need help creating my combobox.

Thank you !

My code :

```
public partial class Repair : Form
{


    public Repair()
    {
        Main pp = new Main();

        InitializeComponent();
        this.label4.Text = pp.label3.Text;

        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
        SqlCommand command1 = maConnexion.CreateCommand();

        if (Program.UserType == "admin")
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Message, FComponent, ReadValue, ValueReference,  RepairingTime FROM FailAndPass WHERE FComponent IS NOT NULL";
            command1.CommandText = "SELECT Machine, BoardName, BoardNumber FROM FailAndPass WHERE FComponent IS NOT NULL";

        }
        else
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Message, FComponent, ReadValue, ValueReference,  RepairingTime FROM FailAndPass WHERE ReportingOperator IS NULL AND FComponent IS NOT NULL";
            command1.CommandText = "SELECT Machine, BoardName, BoardNumber FROM FailAndPass WHERE ReportingOperator IS NULL AND FComponent IS NOT NULL";

        }

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        sda1.Fill(dt1);

        DataColumn dcIsDirty = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
        DataColumn dcIsDirty1 = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
        dcIsDirty.DefaultValue = false;
        dcIsDirty1.DefaultValue = false;




        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;


        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        combo.HeaderText = "FaultCodeByOp";
        combo.Name = "combo";
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.Add("C-C");
        list.Add("C-O");
        combo.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);



        dt.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty);
        dt1.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty1);

        maConnexion.Close();

        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
        dataGridView2.Columns[3].Visible = false;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;

            }
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                dataGridView2.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }




    }




    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        this.Hide();
        Main ff = new Main();
        ff.Show();




    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();
        string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
        SqlCommand command1 = maConnexion.CreateCommand();


        if (Program.UserType == "admin")
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty)
            {

                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1 + "%");
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1 + "%");
                //command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailAndPass WHERE BoardName LIKE @BoardName OR Machine LIKE @Machine OR SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum OR FComponent LIKE @FComponent";

                command.CommandText = "SELECT Message, FComponent, ReadValue, ValueReference, FaultCodeByOp, RepairingTime FROM FailAndPass WHERE SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum AND FComponent IS NOT NULL";
                command1.CommandText = "SELECT Machine, BoardName, BoardNumber FROM FailAndPass WHERE SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum And FComponent IS NOT NULL";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty)
            {

                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1 + "%");
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1 + "%");
                //command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE (BoardName LIKE @BoardName OR Machine LIKE @Machine OR SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum OR FComponent LIKE @FComponent) AND ReportingOperator IS NULL  ";
                command.CommandText = "SELECT Message, FComponent, ReadValue, ValueReference, FaultCodeByOp, RepairingTime FROM FailAndPass WHERE  (SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum) AND ReportingOperator IS NULL AND FComponent IS NOT NULL  ";
                command1.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Machine, BoardName, BoardNumber FROM FailAndPass WHERE (SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum) AND ReportingOperator IS NULL AND FComponent IS NOT NULL";
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            sda1.Fill(dt1);

            DataColumn dcIsDirty = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
            DataColumn dcIsDirty1 = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
            dcIsDirty.DefaultValue = false;
            dcIsDirty1.DefaultValue = false;
            dt.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty);
            dt1.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty1);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
            maConnexion.Close();

            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
            dataGridView2.Columns[3].Visible = false;

        }






    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {


            if ((row.Cells[6].Value != null) && (bool)row.Cells[6].Value)
            {

                SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
                command = new SqlCommand("update FailAndPass set FaultCodeByOp=@Fault, RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime = @RT, ReportingOperator=@RO WHERE SerialNum=@Serial", maConnexion);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fault", row.Cells[4].Value != null ? row.Cells[4].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", DateTime.Today.ToString("d"));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", row.Cells[5].Value != null ? row.Cells[5].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", this.label4.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", this.textBox1.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
        }

        maConnexion.Close();
        this.Hide();
        Repair rep = new Repair();
        rep.Show();

    }



    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void ComboboxInDatagridview()
        {
            var dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            combo.HeaderText = "FaultCodeByOp";
            combo.Name = "combo";
            dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { combo });

            ArrayList list = new ArrayList() { "C-C", "C-O" };

            var rowindex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmbCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1["combo", rowindex];
            //Or
            //var columnindex = 0;
            //DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmbCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1[columnindex, rowindex];
            cmbCell.DataSource = list;  
        }
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I was on holiday. I understand the code. Perhaps there is an exception at "Var rowindex = datagridview1.rows.Add()", it say "System.InvalidOperationException : Impossible adding the lines to the collection Datagridview by programming when the controle are link to the data." ?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having other solutions ? I've tried something else :

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();


        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList(); //{ "C-C", "C-O", "Absence composant", "Mauvaise valeur", "Mauvais sens", "Mauvais composant" };
        list1.Add("C-C");
        list1.Add("C-O");


        combo.DataSource = list1;
        combo.HeaderText = "FaultCodeByOp";
        combo.DataPropertyName = "FaultCodeByOp";


        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(combo);
```

didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what i've done, but it is not greyish anymore. Now it is white like other columns.... but it doesnt dropdown, nor show members of the list.